# Обработка множество Query Parameter и возвращал одну ошибку

Tags: golang

> Всем привет, можете подсказать, у меня множество Query Parameter использую с помощью gin-gonic

```
nameCompany := c.Query("nameCompany")
tradeName := c.Query("tradeName")
terminalID := c.Query("terminal")
contract := c.Query("contract")
```

> один endpoint при запросе URL у меня выходит следующие: 
>   http://localhost/merchant?nameCompany=apple
>   http://localhost/merchant?terminal=98790245
>   http://localhost/merchant?contract=7612-EC11/03/09
>
> но при обработки ошибок (отдельно) всех запросов

```
if nameCompany == "" {
      exp := fmt.Log("GetMerchantAll: Parameter error")
      c.JSON(422, exp)
      return
}
if tradeName == "" {
      exp := fmt.Log("GetMerchantAll: Parameter error")
      c.JSON(422, exp)
      return
}
if terminalID == "" {
      exp := fmt.Log("GetMerchantAll: Parameter error")
      c.JSON(422, exp)
      return
}
if contract == "" {
      exp := fmt.Log("GetMerchantAll: Parameter error")
      c.JSON(422, exp)
      return
}
```

> получается если одна переменная хоть и будет false nameCompany дальше
>   код будет отрабатывать он будет true по любому будет ошибка, по коду
>   если у меня nameCompany нету то дальше исполнения не будет.
>
> Вопрос: Как грамотна обработать ошибки (по одному) или есть ли в gin
>   gonic которое сможет обработать множество Query Parameters и при этом
>   обрабатывал одну ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нашел выход из данной ситуации. Вообщем создаете переменную типа bool
>   сразу инициализировать присвоить значение false, затем проверяете в условии c
>   приходящими Query Parameter.

```
        foundQuery := false      


        if nameCompany != "" || tradeName != "" || terminalID != "" || contract != "" {
            foundQuery = true
        }
        if foundQuery == false {
            exp := fmt.Log("GetMerchantAll: Parameter error")
          c.JSON(422, exp)
          return
        }
```